# TreeMap with no unique key

Tags: java, java-6

I use a TreeMap class for store messages information with their priority in my application.
I've used a treeMap class for do it because this class order automatically the element based on the key value, for example i have this situation :

```
enum Priority { HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW }
TreeMap<Priority,String> tMap = new TreeMap<Priority,String>();
```

I use the key (priority of the message) for automatically order messages based on the priority severity, but the problem is that in TreeMap the key is unique then if i try to insert two messages with the same priority the first is overwritten ....

How can i change this behaviour and disable unique constraint on TreeMap?

Is there a class like TreeMap that allow to put the same Key for multiple element ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can i change this behaviour and disable unique constraint on TreeMap?

You can't.  The uniqueness of keys is a fundamental invariant of the `Map` interface.

> Is there a class like TreeMap that allow to put the same Key for multiple element ?

You can implement this as a `Map<Priority,List<String>>` and manage the lists yourself.  This is a good option if (for example) you want to process the messages for a given priority in fifo order.

Alternatively, you can use a `MultiMap` class; e.g. from [Apache commons collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) or [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: if you need FIFO order, ArrayDeque is a lot better option than list, probably `Map<Priority,Queue<String>>`

Comment: If the OP really has only three priorities he should skip the `Map` altogether and just use three separate `Queue`s.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the TreeMultimap class in the Google Guava library.

Answer (score 0):

You might want another collection type altogether.  But if you're intent on using TreeMap, then:

1) Consider using a more complex Priority class.  Perhaps create a priority type that has both the base priority (HIGH) and a unique number that's incremented every time you get a new one.  Then implement equals, hash, Comparable, etc. using that extra value.

2) For each priority, the value can be a Collection.  Retrieve the value for the given priority, and append the new value on the end of the retrieved collection.  At that point, though, using a TreeMap is a bit of overkill.

Also, have a look at [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use another structure rather than a treemap.

A map is a map and the  behavior is what it is, so in a map you cannot have the same key twice by definition.